# DataFrame creation - reindexing

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, pandas

I keep getting this error in pandas:

```
raise Exception('Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index '
Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Which I understand will happen if the column names are the same while trying to make a `DataFrame` from a dictionary.

However, mine are not.

Here is the dictionary I am using - which looks something like this - quite like that given in the tutorial, does not work:

```
d = {'Sample1': 4.121025    0.306828
4.119957    0.335473
4.096208    0.331831
...
0.824808    0.366679
0.745721    0.586742
Length: 406, 'Sample2': 3.444444    0.937468
3.315508    0.855920
...
0.928144    0.236640
0.918519    0.232346
Length: 991}
```

This is the code I am using to generate this dictionary, the details of some of it are not relevant, but the spec.Y and spec.X are just numpy arrays:

```
d = dict()
for tab in self.tab_list:
    spec = tab.temp_spectra
    name = str(spec.spectra_name)
    d[name] = pd.Series(spec.Y, index=spec.X)
    print(name)
print(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

Any ideas why this error might be showing up so I can know what to go after to fix?  The column names do not appear to be it, and I was operating under the assumption that the indices can match or not - it shouldn't matter - which is why I am using this package to being with.  I want the 'hashtable' type of feel where the X array can be different or the same and the overlap will put values in the same row or create a new row if needed such that all of it can be viewed together.

***EDIT:***

I figured out the solution had to do with a duplicate entry in the index of one of my datasets (one of my datasets was created on plotly by tracing by hand and therefore got two Y values for one X value).
I will give a few examples of this in the answer to my own question.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example that shows the error?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I usually prepare a small compilable sample to try that reproduces the error but this time I could not figure out what was wrong as the small compilable script I wrote would work completely.  Therefore it is something with my specific data type or some mystery that I can't yet figure out.  My hope is that someone may have experience or insight into this type of problem to suggest something.  I'm adding a small compilable script now.

Answer (score 1):

Always check if you have 2 Y values for one X value, or two values per index for a data frame.
I got one of the datasets by hand tracing a graph on plotly and creating the data that way which gave 2 y values for one X.

To illustrate:
Here is a small script which is compilable:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def f(i):
    return np.random.rand(i,)

# number of points in two spectra (two separate spectra of different length)
# possibly obtained on different equipment such that the pixels/values don't align
n1 = 450
n2 = 950
X1 = np.sort(f(n1))
X2 = np.sort(f(n2))
Y1 = f(n1)
Y2 = f(n2)

# make dataframe from the spectra
d = dict()
d['1'] = pd.Series(Y1, index=X1)
d['2'] = pd.Series(Y2, index=X2)
print(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

Here is one that is not, and returns the error I was getting:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def f(i):
    return np.random.rand(i,)

# number of points in two spectra (two separate spectra of different length)
# possibly obtained on different equipment such that the pixels/values don't align
n1 = 450
n2 = 950
# store X array to duplicate a value within it
X_ = f(n1)
X1 = np.sort(np.append(X_,X_[0]))
X2 = np.sort(f(n2))
Y_ = f(n1)
Y1 = np.append(Y_,Y_[0])
Y2 = f(n2)

# make dataframe from the spectra
d = dict()
d['1'] = pd.Series(Y1, index=X1)
d['2'] = pd.Series(Y2, index=X2)
print(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```